# Xcode 10 no breakpoints are hit and app launches blank

Tags: xcode, xcode10

Just updated to Xcode 10 :( and nothing works anymore.

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

App launches and turns black right away.

- I'm running a debug scheme
- Code optimization is turned off
- I have removed main.storyboard from my app setting

It doesn't even hot my breakpoints, I have a breakpoint on the first line of Appldegate and it's not getting hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a breakpoint on the first line of Appldegate and it's not getting hit

Exactly so. The breakpoint is not being hit because your method is not being called. It's not being called because Cocoa can't see that it's there. Cocoa can't see that it's there because *you* have hidden it!

It's all about the relationship between Objective-C and Swift, and how Objective-C sees what's in your Swift code.

The problem is the keyword `private`. This causes Cocoa (which is Objective-C) to be unable to see that you have implemented `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. It can't see it so it doesn't call it. Delete that keyword and you're good to go.

Comment: hmmmm interesting I didn't manually make it private, it was suggested by Xcode as it was converting code to swift 4.2. But that fixed it thx

Comment: Weird. The converter certainly does some strange things, but that's not one I've ever seen it do (and I've converted literally hundreds of projects).